# Assets problem (/cpresources/transforms/) after update to Craft Client 2.5.2750

Tags: assets

Hi I've just updated to Craft 2.5 but ran into a problem. All my assets are now broken (also showen broken assets icons). I've cleared my cache, went to my craft_tasks table and adjusted the running task there but still it won't show me my assets again...

Any suggestions someone?

Comment: Are you on an Ubuntu 14.04 server?

Comment: Just downgraded to 2.4.2726 and everything works again...

Comment: Can you submit a ticket from your dashboard's Get Help widget and let it send along your log files?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue but I was tinkering with Elements API. The JSON payload gave me that `cpresources/transforms/` but once I clicked on the link it shows the proper image with the transforms applied.

Upon returning to the JSON printout, the URL for the assets looks correct. In my case it is pointing to the S3 bucket I had setup previously.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any transforms configured?

I would double check your asset source **File System Path** is correct. Before 2.5 I had mine set incorrectly but `image.url('<transform_handle>')` still worked.

Also, try to upload an image through an asset field and see if you get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

At any point did you have to add the line `extension=imagick.so` in your php.ini file? Even though it was recommended by my webhost (Fused Network) at the time , it was causing ImageMagick to misbehave and filling my public_html directory with core dumps. They were able to figure out the problem and deleting that line solved it.

Comment: Just to be clear this will disable Imagick all-together and you'll be falling back to using GD.